# How to access parent HTML element from component?

Tags: angular

Just like in the question - I have a child component, and I would like to know what is the width of the parent element. How can I do that?

Comment: There is no Angular way, except when the parent component type is known at build time, then it can be injected to the constructor of the child.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41171686/angular2-v-2-3-have-a-directive-access-a-formcontrol-created-through-formcontr?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Inject the element itself:

```
constructor(private elRef: ElementRef){}
```

access the native elements parent:

```
ngOnInit() {
  console.log(this.elRef.nativeElement.parentElement);
}
```

Comment: It will work but it's not a good practice to access the native elements directly.

Comment: @BenRichards. Suppose you have two components like this: `<parent><div><child></child></div></parent>`. How would you get parent's DOM element from `ChildComponent`? I know I could easily get `ParentComponent˙instance inside child by simply adding it as a constructor parameter, but I don't know how to get the actual element?

Comment: I've tried this but it doesn't retrieve the computed parent `style`.

Answer (score 9):

You can access closest parent DOM element by looking up with `this.elRef.closest` and some selector that matches that parent

```
constructor(private elRef: ElementRef){}

ngOnInit() {
   const parentElement = this.elRef.closest('.parent-element-class')
}
```

Comment: closest is NOT supported by internet explorer, so...

Comment: internet explorer is obsolete

Comment: you missed a `nativeElement`
`this.elRef.nativeElement.closest('view-area-view')`