# Angular2 v.2.3 - Have a directive access a FormControl created through formControlName syntax

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

So I'm trying to make a directive that can manipulate a FormControl.

It seems that if I use the long syntax for declaring form controls in the template instead, I can pass the control to a directive to do stuff with it as a direct @Input() bind; i.e.: With the following template:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
    <input type="text" id="myText" [formControl]="myForm.controls['myText']" my-directive>
</form>
```

And the following component logic:

```
@Component({
    // Properties go here.
})
class MyComponent {
    myForm: FormGroup;

    constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
        // Constructor logic...
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.myForm = this.fb.group({
            "myText": [""]
        });
    }
}
```

The directive would look like:

```
@Directive({
    selector: "[my-directive]"
})
class MyDirective {
    Input() formControl: FormControl;
}
```

But if I were using the formControlName syntax in the template instead:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
    <input type="text" id="myText" formControlName="myText" my-directive>
</form>
```

How would I reference the (implicitly?) made FormControl in the directive?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. You can apply a directive to a reactive input with either method of template binding, `formControlName="someName"` or `[formControl]="myForm.controls['someName']"` near as I can tell it doesn't make a difference. If you post your directive and why its not working for you then perhaps you can get an answer.

Comment: As far as I know, the formControlName syntax doesn't place the FormControl instance on the element, so without an explicit binding, I don't know how to access it. I've edited the question, hopefully it's more clear.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

If you utilize `NgControl`, `ElementRef`, `HostListener` and constructor injection we can have a directive applicable to form controls from reactive forms in either `formControlName` or `[formControl]` guise and even template driven forms:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from "@angular/core";
import { NgControl } from "@angular/forms";

@Directive({
  selector: '[my-directive]'
})
export class MyDirective {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private control : NgControl) { }

  @HostListener('input',['$event']) onEvent($event){
    let valueToTransform = this.el.nativeElement.value;
    // do something with the valueToTransform
    this.control.control.setValue(valueToTransform);
  }
}
```

Here's an [applicable demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/rllNyE07uPhUA6UfiLkU?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about NgControl. Just for understanding though... 1) this.control will evaluate to a FormControlDirective, a FormControlName directive, or an NgModel directive based on however we're making the form? 2) this.control.control is the FormControl instance used by this.control, and the directives listed in 1) all have this? 3) Changes in this.control.control will apply to this.control? (e.g. this.control.control.markAsPristine() will set this.control.pristine to true?)

Comment: 1) Correct, 2) Also correct but depending on when you instantiate the control it may be undefined in the directive constructor (which is weird, but related to the lifecycle events) 3) Yes.

Comment: This doesn't work with when a directive also acts as a validator. It causes cyclic dependency.

Comment: @e-cloud this is actually normal as validate method of validator directive takes the control as parameter. You don't need to inject it.

Comment: at first I thought "this.control.control.setValue" was a typo, so I wrote "this.control.setValue", which did not compile

Comment: I was using ngModelChange event  but there was some issue with that.. later switched to input event it worked fine..

Comment: Is there anyway to fire this immediately to transform when the component loads on the formControl's default value instead of only if you type in the input?

Comment: I'm having an issue with injecting NgControl. I get 'No provider for NgControl!'. Adding it to providers in module doesn't work because it's not an Injectable. Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49437951

Comment: i'm only seeing "loading..." in plunker

Comment: I get error
`Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Answer (score 6):

@silentsod answer would work flawlessly. 
1. if you need to handle multiple events like key-press up/down or any other events,  then you can go with below approach. 
 2. Also, it's better to define events in the directive itself.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef} from "@angular/core";
import { NgControl } from "@angular/forms";

@Directive({
  selector: '[my-directive]',
  host: {
   '(input)':'onEvent($event)',
   '(keydown.backspace)': 'onEvent($event, true)'
})
export class MyDirective {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private control : NgControl) { }

  public onEvent($event, someEvent){
    let valueToTransform = this.el.nativeElement.value;
    // do something with the valueToTransform
    if(someEvent) {
    //do something 
    }
    this.control.control.setValue(valueToTransform);
  }
}
```

In the Html

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
<input type="text" id="myText" formControlName="myText" my-directive>
</form>
```