# Cannot read property 'value' of undefined while testing a custom directive which gets an injected form control in Angular using jasmine

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine

I am writing test cases using jasmine karma to test a custom directive.
The directive is used on an input box of type text and prevents alphabets from being entered. The form control is injected by Angular here.
[Reference answer to add NgControl to access FormControl value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41175292/10411625)

```
export class PreventAlphaDirective {
    public regex = //get some regex values from a const file
    
    constructor(public formControl: NgControl) {} //injected by Angular. Having difficulty here to pass form control value from jasmine I GUESS

    @HostListener('input', ['$event'])
    input(event: KeyboardEvent) {
        const val = this.formControl.control.value;
        let inp = '';
        for (const char of val) {
           if (char.match(this.regex.NUMBERS)) {
             inp += char;
           }
        }
      this.formControl.control.setValue(inp);
    }
}
```

I am new to Angular and after reading articles on how to test a custom directive, I read about creating a test component.

I tried the following. But the test case does not cover the above input method and mostly form control value is not set.

Please help.

Here the code of my testing component and spec file

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-testingcomponent',
template:
    `<form [formGroup]="testForm">     
     <input type="text" formControlName="amount" appPreventAlpha />
    </form> `,
    styleUrls: ['./testingcomponent.component.scss'],
    })
export class TestingcomponentComponent implements OnInit {
       constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }
       public testForm: FormGroup;
       ngOnInit() {
           this.testForm = this.fb.group({
           amount: ['12345', [Validators.required]],
           });
       }
    }
```

Spec file

```
describe('TestingcomponentComponent', () => {
let component: TestingcomponentComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestingcomponentComponent>;
let inputElement: DebugElement;

beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule],
        declarations: [TestingcomponentComponent, PreventAlphaDirective],
    });
})); 

beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestingcomponentComponent);
  fixture.detectChanges();
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  inputElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input'));
});
```

Here this is the test case

```
it('for keypress input', () => {
     inputElement.triggerEventHandler('input', {});
     fixture.detectChanges();
     // did not expect anything for now. Just checking code is covered or not
});
```

Update: Here is the error while running the ng test

```
ERROR: 'ERROR', TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
at Object.eval [as handleEvent]
```

Comment: Now I don't get the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined` but rather `SPEC HAS NO EXPECTATIONS for keypress input`

Comment: Is it working for you?

Comment: Yes, it works with Angular 9

Comment: I am using Angular 8

Comment: @yurzui, can you please check whether ng test will cover the input method in the directive?

Answer (score 0):

I think more straightforward way is to create a test component for that with a control property and use your directive in a component template. You actually started to do so in `app-testingcomponent` but I don't see in your spec files that you compile both of you component and directive.

I don't think component redefine in needed in spec file

Comment: initially while posting the question, I forgot to set form control to the test component. Please check now @s-f

Comment: I don't think component redefine in needed in spec file - I did not understand what you meant by this.

Comment: >I did not understand what you meant by this. 
you don't have this code anymore

Comment: Yes. Please check now. I have removed some code that I tried.